# Laravel search by optionals items

Tags: php, laravel

i would like to create simple ability for my users to search database table as an optional items, for example search by name or mobile or email. to create this ability i'm created this simple controller:

```
class SearchTransactionController extends Controller
{
    public function search(Request $request)
    {
        $query = BuyCard::select('*');
        foreach ($request->only(['name', 'mobile', 'email']) as $key => $value) {
            if (strlen($value) > 0) {
                $query->where($key, 'LIKE', "%$value%");
            }
        }
        $query->orderBy('id', 'DESC');
        $data = $query->paginate(15);
        return view('report_buycard_transactions.index')
            ->with('info', $data);
    }
}
```

all name,mobile,email is optional for search but my code dont correct search in database and return all columns

Comment: After the call to `orderBy`, what does `dd($query->toSql(), $query->getBindings())` show?

Comment: @patricus yes, i get `"select * from buy_card_transactions"`

Comment: Before the foreach, what does `dd($request->only(['name', 'mobile', 'email']))` show?

Answer (score 0):

it's because adding multiple `->where()` calls mean it attempts to find only rows where the search string is in all 3 of those columns, try doing this:

```
class SearchTransactionController extends Controller
{
    public function search(Request $request)
    {
        $query = BuyCard::select('*');
        $first = true;
        foreach ($request->only(['name', 'mobile', 'email']) as $key => $value) {
            if (strlen($value) > 0) {
                if($first){
                    $query->where($key, 'LIKE', "%$value%");
                    $first = false;
                } else {
                    $query->orwhere($key, 'LIKE', "%$value%");
                }
            }
        }
        $query->orderBy('id', 'DESC');
        $data = $query->paginate(15);
        return view('report_buycard_transactions.index')
            ->with('info', $data);
    }
}
```

Comment: `$data = $query->count();` always return all records count